# Search all articles and receive body in single SOSL?

Tags: apex, knowledge

Is there a way to search articles from multiple article types and receive back custom fields for each article type with a single SOSL? Sample knowledge bases query the KnowledgeArticleVersion table. This just gives back the ID and URL to the article. I need the article "body" which is stored in the custom field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for a particular keyword in your custom field ? In that case if you search for a keyword (e.g. : 'test') you could use something like :

```
FIND {test} RETURNING
    Article_Type1__kav(Id WHERE PublishStatus='Online' AND Language='en_US'),
    Article_Type2__kav(Id WHERE PublishStatus='Online' AND Language='en_US')
```

This search would include your custom fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select which fields to return, right after opening bracket in [RETURNING](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_returning.htm).

```
FIND {MyProspect} RETURNING Contact(FirstName, LastName LIMIT 10), Account(Name, Industry)
```